Ubuntu 24.04 suspend not work on Acer Aspire 5
Install fresh ubuntu 24.04 on laptop Acer aspire 5
Problem is: Laptop don't suspend, just turn off screen and all.
systemctl suspend just turn off screen and nothing else. After hit any key or clisk mous/touchpad open login screen and password prompt.
I'm try nvidia 535 and 550 driver. The result is same. Please tell me which way to look, I am attaching the logs.
sudo journalctl  --since="-1 minutes" -> https://pastebin.com/7tTYiuEX 
sudo dmesg -> https://pastebin.com/Ywe1hR1w
Logs just after resume after systemctl suspend command

no, swap is off. 32Gb ram work perfect without swap

I was running the nvidia-550 drivers in my instance. I found that I had a series of unmet dependencies after running all apt update and apt upgrade. Once I did sudo apt --fix-broken install it removed the obsolete packages and dependencies and sorted it for the most recent kernel.
I did have an issue with dpkg and needed to run sudo dpkg --force-all -i <path to 550 deb> before running --fix-broken install
I hope this helps/gives some direction to fixing your problem! I've not had any issues with it since then, the resume works perfectly.
